# Docker Compose: can't connect to my MySQL container

Tags: mysql, docker

I'm getting the following error when I try to connect to my MySQL container from another container:

```
$ mysql -h127.0.0.1 -uroot
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (115)
```

I can see that my container is running on port 3306:

```
$ docker container ls
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                 PORTS                    NAMES
a341fa5075c2   5961245d3135   "httpd-foreground"       3 minutes ago    Up 3 minutes  127.0.0.1:8080->80/tcp    sfcoding_cwj_1
e7683d546ad1   4da164162573   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   28 minutes ago   Up 3 minutes  127.0.0.1:3306->3306/tcp  sfcoding_mysql_1
```

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
---
version: '3.8'

services:
  cwj:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app:cached
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:8080:80"

  mysql:
    image: mariadb:10.5.8
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mariadb
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "true"

volumes:
  db_data: {}
```

Any ideas as to why it won't connect?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I need to make my host match my service name, which is `mysql`.

```
mysql -h127.0.0.1 -uroot # does not work
mysql -hmysql -uroot # works
```

Comment: Connect from where? Judging by your answer I'm guessing the other container. You should probably add that info to the question as it's not very clear atm.

Comment: Good point. Another container. Question updated.